# Probability that blood samples are of different types

Tags: probability

In a certain population, the proportions of people having blood of types $O$, $A$, $B$ and $AB$ are $42$%, $28$%, $18$% and $12$%, respectively. If blood samples are taken from four people, then what probability can be given to the proposition that they are all of different types?

The question states that if there are $n$ people in the population, then $(0.42 \times n)$, $(0.28 \times n)$, $(0.18 \times n)$ and $(0.12 \times n)$ people have blood types $O$, $A$, $B$ and $AB$, respectively.

Now, if the question instead stated that for every person, the probability of them having blood type $O$, $A$, $B$ or $AB$ is $42$%, $28$%, $18$% or $12$%, respectively, then the question would have been easy enough to solve.
The answer would simply be $0.42 \times 0.28 \times 0.18 \times 0.12$, due to the independence of events.

But, in the original question, as soon as the first person is chosen to be tested, his blood type would affect the probability of the blood type of the next person to be tested, and so on, as the events are now dependent.

So, I guess that without knowing the size of the population, it is not possible to determine the required probability.

Is this analysis correct?

Comment: You need to multiply by $4!$. Also, have you heard of the 5% rule? It states that if your sample size over your population size is less than 5%, then you may assume that you're sampling with replacement. This is certainly the case here since your sample size is $4$ whereas your population size is enormous.

Comment: To emphasize... often times for probability questions like this the size of the population is assumed to be "*large*" which makes it so that even though in reality there may be some dependence of events, the error caused by assuming the events to be independent is so incredibly insignificant that we intentionally ignore it.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yeah, sorry. I missed that 4!. Thanks for your help.